# how to add command line parameter in Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.7, advanced-installer

I have been looking for a good answer for my following simple enough question.

I have an interactive Wix installer, which works perfect. The user needs to accept the licence agreement in the interactive setup to carry on the setup. Now, I need to have a silent installer where the user will accept the same licence agreement by entering a command line parameter like ACCEPT-EULA=YES.
Could anyone please guide me how I should manage to implement this in wxs file? I am not using MSVC by the way. I have tried

```
<util:XmlFile Action="setValue" ...
```

but got tons of different sort of errors.

I'd greatly appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an error custom action scheduled first in the install execute sequence with a condition of UILevel < 5 and Not ACCEPTEULA~="YES"`

The [UILevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is defined here.  5 means full UI so you don't want this CA to run.  < 5 means some form of silent installation so you only want this custom action to fire when the property doesn't equal (case insensitive) "yes".

```
<CustomAction Id="RequireEulaWhenSilent" Error="You must accept the EULA by passing ACCEPTEULA=YES when performing a silent installation."/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RequireEulaWhenSilent" Before="AppSearch"><![CDATA[UILevel<5 and Not ACCEPTEULA~="YES" and Not Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Of course you now have a problem that if they aren't logging the install they won't know why the installer failed.  Personally I think this is an invented requirement by upper management and I always push back when given this problem.  Otherwise you get into crazy land like [this](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2007/03/silently-installing-net-framwork-legal.html).

Comment: Hi Christopher,
I tried your code but installation fails at the beginning even though I give the necessary parameter. When I check the log file, I see "Product: App Launcher -- Installation failed. Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: App Launcher. Product Version: 1.1.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Test. Installation success or error status: 1605."

Comment: What command line did you run?  Did you perform a verbose log?

Comment: Christophe, everything is working perfect at the moment but I got the Error message that you typed in your message when uninstalling. So, I guess UILevel comes <5 when uninstalling.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  I forgot to add something. Let me revise my answer.  Yes uninstall has a Basic UI by default unless you perform it from a maintenance install and then select remove.  I've added the "not Not Installed" expression so that the condition only applies to initial installation.

Comment: Awesome!!!
Another small question. Can we show the error message that is to be shown when eula is not accepted in the command line as a response instead of a popup message? Since it is a silent install, I want it to be a really silent without having any popup windows :)

Comment: What command line did you use?  A type 19 should just write an error to the log file and exit silently.  That's it built in behavior.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does exactly how you described. No problem anymore on this topic.

Comment: Chris, what about silent patch installation, silent major upgrade scenarios, and interactive uninstall. I am not sure those conditions handle all scenarios correctly? I haven't tested it.

Comment: A silent major upgrade would require eula acceptance again since it's not considered installed yet.  A patch is already an installed product.  An interactive uninstall is already installed.  Ya, I think I got it all right but as always, trust but verify.  #nowarrantyexpressedorimplied

Comment: These conditions are so easy to get wrong that they must be tested Dundar. Here is a cheat sheet: http://www.flexerasoftware.jp/webdocuments/PDF/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf for different conditions. InstallExecuteSequence is used for install, modify, repair, self-repair, minor / major / small upgrade, uninstall, patch and patch uninstall and resumed suspended installs and probably even more. Plenty to get wrong and lots of testing scenarios.

Comment: Which is pretty much why I wouldn't even implement this.  But I wield a lot more power at the companies I work then most setup developers do.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of agree with Chris, reject this requirement and put the license agreement inside the main application EXE file with a flag per user for whether the particular user has seen and accepted the license agreement or not.

This is assuming that this is really important legally, because it is a serious annoyance to every user in my opinion. However, arguably having a system administrator accept the license agreement on every user's behalf is probably not great legally. I am not sure how this is handled by larger companies actually. You can certainly ask your marketing and sales guys what they think of this - it is their issue.

I think the conditions suggested could work, but it all depends on where you put the custom action in the sequence, whether you use major upgrade patches or similar unusual things. Ideally you should condition so tightly that the action can only run when it is really intended.

**Test at least these scenarios:**

- Fresh install, both silent and interactive
- Major upgrade, both silent and interactive
- Uninstall, both silent and interactive
- Modify (start from Add/Remove Programs)

And use the [**MSI condition cheat sheet**](http://www.flexerasoftware.jp/webdocuments/PDF/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf) to help you.

Comment: My silent installer is for large companies to push company pc's laptops the application. Since it is silent, user has no idea what is being installed in his/her computer. Therefore, showing licence agreement has no meaning. Therefore, we go for such a solution. I have no idea about its legality.

Comment: I would think showing the license agreement may then be a requirement for the application itself?

Comment: Actually it is pretty much standard licence agreement that contains mostly the open source software that we use in our software. And of course some other legal words for liabilities and so on.